# How can I find Feature importance from sklearn api, after I have converted my categorical variables into dummy variables?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

After we have converted our categorical variables to dummy variables for training the model. We tend to find feature importance. But sklearn's model.feature_importance_ object returns feature impotance for every dummy variable, rather than the original categorical variable. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because the dummy variables are used to train the model, you cannot find the importance of the original categorical variable. It is mathematically impossible thing.